# Retrieve the Relationship object in Neomodel

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I am using Neomodel and Python for my project. I have a number of nodes defined and am storing relevant information on the relationships between them. However I can't seem to find a mechanism for retrieving the relationship object itself to be able to use the attributes - I can only filter by the relationship attribute to return the Nodes.

```
class MyRelationship(StructuredRel):
    source = StringProperty()
    
class Person(StructuredNode):
    uid=UniqueIdProperty()
    first_name = StringProperty()
    last_name = StringProperty()
    
    people = RelationshipTo('Person', "PERSON_RELATIONSHIP", model = MyRelationship)
```

I have a number of relationships of the same type [PERSON_RELATIONSHIP] between the same two nodes, but they differ by attribute. I want to be able to iterate through them and print out the to node and the attribute.

Given an Object `person` of type `Person`

`for p in person.people:`
gives me the Person objects

`person.people.relationship(p).source` always gives me the value for the first relationship only

A `Traversal` also seems to give me the Person objects as well

The only way it seems to get a Relationship object is on `.connect`.

Any clues? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled over the same problem and managed to solve it like below. But i am not sute if it is the most performant solution.

If you already have a `Person` node object in variable `person`:

```
for p in person.people:
    r = person.people.relationship(p)
```

Or iterating over all `Person` nodes:

```
for person in Person.nodes.all():
    for p in person.people:
        r = person.people.relationship(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've checked the [neomodel source code](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/blob/2957f74a117f51dccf4b84129dc0b68a03e7bf6a/neomodel/relationship_manager.py#L134) and there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve what you want in a more efficient way than what Roman said.

but you could always use cypher queries.

```py
from neomodel import db
from models import Person, MyRelationship

john = Person.nodes.get(name='John')

results, cols = db.cypher_query(f"""MATCH (node)-[rel]-(neighbor)
                                    WHERE id(node)={john.id}
                                    RETURN node, rel, neighbor""")

rels = {}
neighbors = []

for row in results:
    neighbor = Person.inflate(row[cols.index('neighbor')])
    neighbors.append(neighbor)
    rel = MyRelationship.inflate(row[cols.index('rel')])
    rels[neighbor.id] = rel
```

Then, now that you've stored all neighbors and the relationships between them, you can loop through them like so:

```py
for neighbor, rel in rels:
    print(f"john has a friendship with {neighbor} which has the source {rel.source}")
```

Hope this helps!

Ethan

Comment: Thank you. Yes that is what I did in the end.